# prolog, a conditional like form

Tags: prolog, probability

well i'm having a hard time working with prolog (gprolog). My problem is this, I've the next predicate:

```
prob(factA,factB,X,first):-   X=<50.
prob(factA,factB,X,second):-  X>50,X=<80.
prob(factA,factB,X,none):-  X>80,X=<100.
```

that is factA have 50% of probability of occur, factB a 30%, and lastly 20% of non of the facts occur. Also i've others predicate where change the factB but not factA, also change the X intervals.

Now i have the functor:

```
result(X,Y,N):- random(1,100,I),
  prob(X,Y,I,N).
```

this predicate tells what is N for X an Y in prob. This predicate handle the case:

```
result(factA,factB,N).
```

but now i have to handle:

```
result(factB,factA,N).
```

and it will return a valid result, any idea?, i did something like this:

```
result(X,Y,N):- Y = factA,
     random(1,100,I),
     prob(Y,X,I,N).
            J is 100-I,
     prob(Y,X,J,N).
```

but this doesn't manage well the 'none' result.

Somebody has any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Please fix the formatting, it's hard to read like this. In particular, indent all code by 4 spaces: this will preserve endlines and set it into monospace.

Comment: Are your probabilities tied to positions, or to the fact identities? I.e. in your example of `result(factB, factA, N)`, which one do you want to have 50%: `factA` or `factB`? Or let me rephrase that: is `result` always going to return 50% for `first`, 30% for `second` and 20% for `none`, or is it 50% for `factA` in X or Y position, 30% for `factB` (in X or Y position) and 20% for `none`? By your last snippet, I'd say the latter?

Comment: I redid the formatting, but changed nothing else: it looks like you have a . where you should have a , in your last clause's 3rd last line: "prob(Y,X,I,N)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at my comment above: if `first` is 50% (and with some optimisation if you "know" random value will be between 1 and 100):

```
prob(X,first):- X=<50, !.
prob(X,second):- X=<80, !.
prob(X,none).
```

I guess this is not what you meant since it does not depend on facts at all, so they're not needed as arguments.

Thus, assuming `factA` is 50%, a bit more complex but basically the same idea as yours:

```
fact_prob(factA, 50).
fact_prob(factB, 30).

random_fact(X, _, I, R) :-
  fact_prob(X, XP),
  I <= XP, !,
  R = first.
random_fact(X, Y, I, R) :-
  fact_prob(X, XP),
  fact_prob(Y, YYP),
  XYP is XP + YP,
  I <= XYP, !,
  R = second.
random_fact(_, _, _, none).
```

Disclaimer: I never worked with gprolog, you might need to adjust details to your dialect.